# HiveDriver ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, maven, hive

I have created a maven project with a dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I'm facing the below exception for `private static String driverName = "org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";`

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at sample.HiveJdbcClient.main(HiveJdbcClient.java:18)
```

Comment: Why would Hadoop core dependencies contain any Hive code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you need this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
    <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Change version depending on what HiveServer2 is running

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hive/hive-jdbc/2.3.2

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Failed to open new session: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.authorize.AuthorizationException): User: hduser is not allowed to impersonate hduser

Comment: @PraveenMandadi you should ask this as a separate question, as it has nothing to do with this one